# Pandas: How to split a column of a dataframe, which follows powerlaw into two based on frequency distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, sampling, power-law

I have a data frame of 1 million records with 5 columns.

```
unique_index,name,company_name,city_id,state_id
```

Column, `company_name`, has 100k unique records. This follows a power law. Top 5000 `company_names` cover 70% of the records.

[image: Power law]

I want to take equal number of samples from the companies which contribute to the top 5000 of the data and from the remaining set.

I tried `pd.qcut(df['company_name'],[0.25,1]`. This gave me the below error:
`TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= float()`. Can `qcut` not be applied to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try grabbing the top companies by `value_counts()` and then creating a new column with `True/False` if it's in/out of the top companies. I think it would look something like this:

```
top5000 = df['company_name'].value_counts().index[0:5000].tolist()
df['InTop'] = df['company_name'].isin(top5000)
```

This would allow you to sample from the group where `df['InTop'] == True` and the group where `df['InTop'] == False`